# Is there any log file or view stores data about user last transaction with database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wondered if there is any table or view which is storing last updates, scripts run by SQL plus or transaction or any changes run by the system? If you look at the SQL Developer they have SQL history. I need something very similar to that but contain or information with time and date and maybe number of execution etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Data Capture (CDC) allows Oracle Data Integrator to track changes in source data caused by other applications. When running integration interfaces, thanks to CDC, Oracle Data Integrator can avoid processing unchanged data in the flow.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/integrate.1111/e12643/data_capture.htm[CDC oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/integrate.1111/e12643/data_capture.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is there a table log with commands. Maybe **[FLASHBACK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9012.htm)** tables will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several data dictionary views that contain information about SQL statements, transactions etc:

- V$SQL
- V$SESSION
- V$TRANSACTION
  ...

see [Asktom on V$SQL views](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:385254862843)
and [Oracle documentation on V$SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your needs. If you just want a quick peek at activity history - take a look at `v$active_session_history` - it's not exactly what you're looking for, but still something.

> V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY displays sampled session activity in the
>   database. It contains snapshots of active database sessions taken once
>   a second. A database session is considered active if it was on the CPU
>   or was waiting for an event that didn't belong to the Idle wait class.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1007.htm

You can then join it with `v$sql` on `sql_id` column and see the sql statement that has been executing at that moment, in case if it is not aged out of shared pool yet.

However, if you need something more detailed and/or reliable - I'd ask your DBA about turning on SQL Tracing or DB Audit.